# How can I get the list sell item of the seller?

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-5

I have 2 table which are product and ps(seller). I want to make a page which will list all the seller product. I'm using if else statement but it is not working. I'm quite new in laravel, please help me.

PsController.php

```
  public function show(){
    $ps = DB::table('ps')->get();
    return view('viewps', ['ps' => $ps]);
  }

  public function view($id){
    $ps = Ps::find($id)
    return view ('views')->with('ps', $ps);
  }

  public function sellitem(){

    $id = DB::table('ps')->get();
    $ps_id = DB::table('product')->get();
    return view('sellitem', ['ps_id' => $ps_id,'id'=>$id]);
  }
```

sellitem.blade.php

```
    @if ($ps_id == $id)
        <div class="searchable-container">
            <div class="items col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 clearfix">
               <div class="info-block block-info clearfix">
                    <div class="square-box pull-left">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user glyphicon-lg"></span>
                    </div>
                    <h5>{{$ps_id->name}}</h5>
                    <h5><img src="{{ asset('images/' . $ps_id->image) }}" height="100" width="100"/> </h5>
                    <h5>Sold by : {{$ps_id->ps_name}}</h5>
                    <h4>  <div class="panel-body"> </h4>

                </div>
            </div>
@else
No records found !
@endif


Route::get('/viewps', 'PsController@show');
Route::get('/viewps/{id}', 'PsController@view')->name('view');
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::get('/sellitem/{ps_id}', 'PsController@sellitem')->name('sellitem');
```

[Product database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J00mi.png)[ps database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQfmh.png)

**Update**

```
PS model

class Ps extends Authenticatable{
use Notifiable;

protected $fillable = [
    'name','lastname','email', 'password', 'username','phone','gender'
];

protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
];

public function product(){
 return $this->hasMany('Product::class'); }
```

Product model

```
class Product extends Model{
public $table = "Product";

protected $fillable = 
['name','description','size','image','price','type','ps_id','ps_name'];

 protected $hidden = [
  'password', 'remember_token',
 ];

 public function ps(){
return $this->belongsTo('Ps::class');
}
```

**New update**
What i want to do is , from viewps page there will be have a link to their sell item which is sellitem.

viewps.blade

```
<div class="box box-info">

        <div class="box-body">
                 <div class="col-sm-6">
                 <div  align="center"> <img alt="User Pic" src="https://x1.xingassets.com/assets/frontend_minified/img/users/nobody_m.original.jpg" id="profile-image1" class="img-circle img-responsive">

            <input id="profile-image-upload" class="hidden" type="file">

                 </div>
          <br>

        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
        <h4 style="color:#00b1b1;">{{ucfirst(trans($ps->name))}} {{ucfirst(trans($ps->lastname))}}</h4></span>
          <span><p>Rating</p></span>
          <span><p><a href="{{ route('sellitem', $ps->id) }}">Lists of Sell Items</a></p></span>
        </div>
```

Sellitem.blade

```
        @if (count($sellProducts) > 0)
      @foreach ($ps as $sellProducts)
         <div class="searchable-container">
                  <div class="items col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 clearfix">
                     <div class="info-block block-info clearfix">
                          <div class="square-box pull-left">
                              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user glyphicon-lg"></span>
                          </div>
                          <h5>{{$ps->name}}</h5>
                          <h5><img src="{{ asset('images/' . $ps->image) }}" height="100" width="100"/> </h5>
                          <h5>Sold by : {{$p->ps_name}}</h5>
                          <h4>  <div class="panel-body"> </h4>

                      </div>
                  </div>
      @endforeach
  @else
        No records found !
  @endif

  </div>
```

@endsection

Comment: @if ($ps_id == $id) why are you comparing object? use `$ps_id->id == $id->id `  Please share your models as well.

Comment: use this in if condition `$ps_id->ps_id == $id->id` and let me know if it works

Comment: your also missing a closing `</div>` in there.  `searchable-container` has no closing tag.

Comment: What does it mean "it doesn't work"? Please read [ask] and clearly state the expected behaviour and how it deviates from that.

Comment: Ya i will need to study a lot .. @Rakib i got error : Use of undefined constant results - assumed 'results'

Comment: that's typo mistake change it to `$results`.

Comment: Error of : Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: change it like this way `return view('sellitem', ['sellProducts' => $results,'ps'=> $ps]);` :)  you will have to understand by seeing the error message

Comment: I gave you solution now it's up to you to move on further by understanding the current code. Please mark my answer as accepted one. Thanks

Comment: Sure , thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following query (We can also use `DB::raw` in the select statement to calculate `sum or`count(*)` )

```
public function sellitem($id){
     $ps = Ps::find($id);
     $query = DB::table('ps')
                ->select('product.id as id',
                    'product.name as name',
                    'product.description as description',
                    'product.type as type',
                    'product.ps_id as ps_id',
                    'product.ps_name as ps_name',
                    'product.size as size',
                    'product.price as price'

                ))
                ->join('product', 'product.ps_id', '=', 'ps.id')
                ->where('product.ps_id','=', $id)
             ;

          $results = $query->get();
         return view('sellitem', ['sellProducts' => $results,'ps'=> $ps]);
  }
```

Then in the `sellitem.blade.php`

use for loop to get values from sellProducts(in this case there will be no need of if condition )

```
@if (count($sellProducts) > 0)
    @foreach ($sellProducts as $sp )
       <div class="searchable-container">
                <div class="items col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 clearfix">
                   <div class="info-block block-info clearfix">
                        <div class="square-box pull-left">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user glyphicon-lg"></span>
                        </div>
                        <h5>{{$sp->name}}</h5>
                        <h5><img src="{{ asset('images/' . $sp->image) }}" height="100" width="100"/> </h5>
                        <h5>Sold by : {{$sp->ps_name}}</h5>
                        <h4>  <div class="panel-body"> </h4>

                    </div>
                </div>
    @endforeach
@else
      No records found !
@endif
```